# How to route all in matchCondition ?

Tags: json, function, azure, proxy

I'm working on a Azure Functions App and i have some issues with the routes, when I add a matching rule with `*` inside, it doesn't work anymore. Anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

When I uncomment one of the other rules or just change the route of `Test Route` from `/{code}` to `/{*code}`, it fails and gives me the `Bad Request` response.

My routing file `proxies.json`

```
{
"$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "Test Route": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/{code}"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://%WEBSITE_HOSTNAME%/api/UrlTester/{code}"
        }
        //,
        //"Let's Encrypt Support" : {
        //    "matchCondition": {
        //        "route": "/.well-known/acme-challenge/{*code}"
        //    },
        //    "backendUri": "https://%WEBSITE_HOSTNAME%/api/LetsEncrypt/{code}"
        //},
        //"Domain Redirect": {
        //    "matchCondition": {
        //        "route": "/{*shortUrl}"
        //    },
        //    "backendUri": "http://%WEBSITE_HOSTNAME%/api/UrlRedirect/{shortUrl}"
        //},
        //"Api": {
        //    "matchCondition": {
        //        "route": "/api/{*path}"
        //    },
        //    "backendUri": "http://%WEBSITE_HOSTNAME%/api/{path}"
        //}
    }
}
```

I'm using this following fork: https://github.com/duijvelshoff/serverless-url-shortener

And this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this github issue](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/50) a catchall {* route redirecting to the same function app will cause a 400 response.

Moving your HTTP triggered functions to a separate function app, and changing the backend URLs will fix your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this explains a lot, since it worked for a few hours. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try something like "route": "id={code}"